# Where can I find 'Authorization' header in http protocol?

Tags: http, https, http-headers, authorization

I need to know where and in which context can I find the `Authorization` header in `HTTP`protocol?

- Is it always in Base64?
- Can it be found only in GET headers or also in POST/PUT?

Answer (score 0):

1) It depends on the authentication scheme. For "Basic" (RFC 7617 soon, previously RFC 2617) it's indeed base 64.

2) It can occur in any HTTP method.